# wordpress jquery missing : after property id

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make a simple accorion menu using jQuery together with Wordpress.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


$j("#leftmenupane p.leftmenu_head").click(function(
{
    $j(this).css({'background-image' : 'url(down.png)'}).next("div.leftmenu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.leftmenu_body").slideUp("slow");
    $j(this).siblings().css({'background-image' : 'url(left.png)'});
});

</script>

<div id="leftmenupane" class="leftmenu_list">
  <p class="leftmenu_head">Header-1</p>
    <div class="leftmenu_body">
        <a href="#">Link-1</a>
        <a href="#">Link-2</a>
        <a href="#">Link-3</a>
        <a href="#">Link-4</a>
    </div>
  <p class="leftmenu_head">Header-2</p>
    <div class="leftmenu_body">
        <a href="#">Link-1</a>
        <a href="#">Link-2</a>
        <a href="#">Link-3</a>
    </div>
  <p class="leftmenu_head">Header-3</p>
    <div class="leftmenu_body">
        <a href="#">Link-1</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

It is actually a sample form some tutorial. But I cannot get it to work. I sense some stupid error here but I am unable to find it. All I get is a " missing: after property id" error in Firebug on line "$j(this).css({'background-image' : 'url(down. ... ".

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the colon to a comma & get rid of ur swirly brackets, like so:

```
$j(this).css('background-image', 'url(down.png)');
$j(this).siblings().css('background-image', 'url(left.png)');
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but it results in the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, try changing the `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` to `j = jQuery.noConflict();`

I only say this because they error you're seeing usually comes up when a variable is not available at compile time. I'm wondering if defining $j almost negates the no conflict or something. Just give it a try.

Comment: Tried `j = jQuery.noConflict();` and changing j to some random variable name (jhkg) to ensure it does not conflict with other variable with no success. But when i try: `$j(this).siblings().css( 'background-image' , 'url(left.png)');` in a javaScript console in Firebug it sais `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` and simple $j returns: `ReferenceError: $j is not defined source=with(_FirebugCommandLine){$j\n};` Looks like $j is not initialized or something.

Comment: Well after you do the j = jQuery.noConflict();, you would then only use j everywhere else. (Don't use $j anymore, since you never declared it)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {

 $j("#leftmenupane p.leftmenu_head").click(function()
 {
  $j(this).css('background-image' , 'url(down.png)').next("div.leftmenu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.leftmenu_body").slideUp("slow");
  $j(this).siblings().css( 'background-image' , 'url(left.png)');
 });

});
```

and it is now working correctly. Thank you guys anyway, as you pushed me into right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

it's probably a syntax error. quoting the line of code above...

```
$j("#leftmenupane p.leftmenu_head").click(function(
```

it looks like you aren't closing your parentheses after the function declaration. try this...

```
$j("#leftmenupane p.leftmenu_head").click(function()
```